# Add linker flag during conan install

Tags: visual-c++, conan

I'm working in a project that uses a number of external libraries. These libraries are included using Conan. The project is primarily written for Unix, but it also need to compile and run on Windows.

My current problem is that Windows defaults `fopen()` to be `O_TEXT`, while Unix expects this to be `O_BINARY`. I have a fix that works for my own code, simply include `binmode.obj` when linking to change this default to O_BINARY.

The problem is that this does not affect my third party libraries. Googling for this didn't turn up much, most suggestions seems to be based on where you are creating your own package and want flags added, rather than how to add flags when using other's packages.

What I have tried so far:

1. Make `binmode.obj` come before libraries, in case the linking order matters. Made no difference.
2. Added `--env 'CL=link binmode.obj'` to `conan install`, but this flag did not end up as part of the compile flags nor link flags.

Any suggestions for what I could try?

EDIT: I was wrong about "CL" taking no effect. This was caused by confusing output. But I did observe that CL seems to be applied for both compiler and linker, which makes it somewhat challenging what flags to give. Using "/link" prefix makes it work with compiler, but does not work with linker.

EDIT 2: More confusions... I didn't realize that the syntax of the CL value was: `"<compile flags> /link <link flags>"`. It affected compile, but not link, however. So this environment variable apparently can't be used to make Conan add a linker flag for autotools based packages.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mats L welcome to our community!
I once had a similar problem and what I end up doing was quite hacky but quite simple also:

On my conan profile located at `~/.conan/profiles/default` or any other profile actually I added an enviromental variable as such:
`CXX=/usr/bin/clang++ -fms-compatibility`. This one made me compile all the c++ sources with this flag (that can understand windows specific code).

So in your case you can  run `which c++` to find the location of your compiler
and edit the CXX environmental variable in the conan profile you use  your final file will probably look like :

```
[settings]
os=Macos
os_build=Macos
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=clang
compiler.version=11
compiler.libcxx=libc++
build_type=Release
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
CXX=c++ --required_flag
```

Some additional notes: You might also want this flag set on your CC enviromental variable .
It's preferable to not change the default profile but copy it (lets say on a file named default_edited_copy) and then invoke the other profile with `conan ... --profile default_edited_copy`

Comment: I agree that was hackish... I didn't try CXX environment variable, but I did try others that automake should listen to like LDFLAGS. Apparently, things were done differently for Windows, which might be the reason for why it didn't work.
In the end, I ended up using libjpeg-turbo instead which uses CMake. Then I could use LDFLAGS environment variable to inject my linker flag...